# mercurial recurring repository corruption

Tags: mercurial, repository, corruption, recurring

I'm getting daily repository corruption on my mercurial.
Every time it says:

```
abort: integrity check failed on data/*classified*:16!
```

i ran hg verify and it said:

```
*classified* files, *classified* changesets, *classified* total revisions
16 integrity errors encountered!
(first damaged changeset appears to be 9259)
```

EDIT: The supposed corruption above turned out to be some changes i did in the files, but it still is actually getting corrupted from time to time so that when i pull it says the repository is corrupted.

Comment: What kind of device/filesystem is this repository running on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. A script i was running was modifying the .hg files.